# How do I reference APA style of screenshot of my data on an app?

Tags: citation-style, reference-request

How do I reference APA style of screenshot of my data on an app? Ex: data location points on Avenza mapping.

Comment: Is screenshotting something really the best option?

Comment: It was the only option. We had to use Avenza to map some trees and then screen shot it for an assignment.

Comment: Are you asking how to cite it *in that assignment*? Or are you somehow reusing it somewhere else? I don't know this program you're using but I second Azor Ahai - a screenshot sounds like a terrible option.

Comment: yes, for my group assignment, I needed to use the Avenza app, plot the trees, find the GPS coordinates then screenshot my results. Now for the report I need to put the screenshot into the report and I have to reference the picture. Would I just reference the app? and the person who's phone we used?

Comment: Since it is explicitly part of an assignment, I would ask the instructor. I presume you have described the method in the paper, and really only need to present the data as a figure? Of course, you can get the coordinates out from Avenza and plot them up in whatever GIS (or other) software that you prefer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Citations/references are for using *other* work.

In your current/first use of some data in a paper, you don't cite it, instead you describe in your methodology section what you did to generate the results. Anyone that reuses those data would then cite *your paper*.

If you use software or hardware in your data collection, it might be relevant to cite that software package or a paper describing the hardware. Alternatively, you typically list reagents and other equipment in-line, like: "We used Widgets (International Widget Corp, London, UK)." rather than the citation system you use for written works.

Of course the rules might differ *for your course* depending on learning goals; in that case the only person you can ask is your instructor.